# Specify a return / redirect URL in Azure AD B2C SAML after successful login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0

Is there a way to specify a URL to which the user should be redirected to after a successful login via Azure AD B2C SAML ?

If there is not an option in Azure, is it possible to use RelayState with a URL ?

Answer (score 1):

In azure, when you set up saml single signon, even in b2c, the saml options are the same, you can specify a relaystate optional parameter, and it will always go there after login.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications#step-1-edit-the-basic-saml-configuration